# How to get a Div to move randomly with radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I’ve been doing some research here for enjoyment to learn JavaScript. I’ve been Googling to find an answer to this, but have had no luck. It could be that I’m a bit of an amateur and don’t know the proper terms to search for, but maybe somebody can steer me in the right direction or help me out.

Anyway, I’m looking for a way to get a div to sit in the center and to randomly move around a page with each radio button. Like, the div is one color and one clicks the first radio button and it will move a little bit from the center, then the middle radio button one will move more, but the last radio button will move very far.

Starting point obvious is the ‘center’ of the page and the ending point does not matter. It just needs to move random at each button pressed.

I’ve got decent HTML and CSS skills, very basic JS skills, and some experience implementing JQuery. Ideally, I’d like to figure this out as the library and the two texts that I have are no help.

Here is what I have so far.

Thanks in advance!!!

```
 <html>
<head>
<style>

div.a {
width: 50px;
height:50px;
background-color:red;
margin:0px;

}
</style>

<script>

 function showStyle() {
     //alert(" ss " );
     var id = document.getElementById("div1");
     var str = "";

     str = str + "position: " + id.style.position + ";";
     str += "<br>top: " + id.style.top;
     str += "<br>left: " + id.style.left;
     str += "<br>width: " + id.style.width;
     str += "<br>height: " + id.style.height;
     document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = str;
     }


function myFunction(){
    var x= document.getElementById("smallRadio");
    x.checked = true;  } 
    function smallRadio() {
    var id = document.getElementById("div1");
    id.style.top = (parseInt(id.style.top) + 50) + "px";
      }

function myFunction(){
    var x= document.getElementById("mediumRadio");
    x.checked = true;  } 
    function smallRadio() {
    var id = document.getElementById("div1");
    id.style.top = (parseInt(id.style.top) + 50) + "px";
      }


function myFunction(){
    var x= document.getElementById("largeRadio");
    x.checked = true;  } 
    function smallRadio() {
    var id = document.getElementById("div1");
    id.style.top = (parseInt(id.style.top) + 50) + "px";
      }


$(document).ready(function(){
    animateDiv();

});

function makeNewPosition(){


    var h = $(window).height() - 50;
    var w = $(window).width() - 50;

    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

    return [nh,nw];    

}

function animateDiv(){
    var newq = makeNewPosition();
    $('.a').animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, function(){
      animateDiv();        
    });

};

</script>
</head>

<body>
<h3>Click</h3>
Small Leap: <input type="radio" id="smallRadio"><br>
Medium Leap: <input type="radio" id="mediumRadio"><br>
Big Leap: <input type="radio" id="largeRadio"><br>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click!</button>

<div class='a'></div>
```

Comment: I will create a fiddle for you. I would also not use function names that are the same, causes errors or will only execute last found. This fiddle may be a different style of coding, but is how I would handle it as a proof of concept.

Comment: How many `myFunction` are there ? Where there is no name for radio buttons ?

Comment: There should be three thats on there. I'm thinking that I need 3 radio buttons in all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way I would probably do it, then you can tweak this as you need. Also, remember when using animation to make the css position set to absolute. A working fiddle can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/unix102/39rps25t/)

CSS

```
div.a {
width: 50px;
height:50px;
background-color:red;
position:absolute;
}
```

HTML

```
<h3>Click</h3>
Small Leap: <input type="radio" id="smallRadio"><br>
Medium Leap: <input type="radio" id="mediumRadio"><br>
Big Leap: <input type="radio" id="largeRadio"><br>

<div class='a' id="mainDiv"></div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).on('change', 'input:radio', function(){
  var $thisRadio = $(this); //gives us a jQuery instance of current radio that triggered the event
    //update functions
  updateDivPosition($thisRadio);
});

function updateDivPosition($target)
{
   var $div = $('#mainDiv');
   var newLeft = 0;
   var newTop = 0;
   var currentPosition = $div.position();

   switch($target.attr("id"))
   {
      case "smallRadio":
            newTop = currentPosition.top + 10;
            newLeft = currentPosition.left + 10;

         break;
      case "mediumRadio":
            newTop = currentPosition.top + 30;
            newLeft = currentPosition.left + 30;      

          break;          
      case "largeRadio":
            newTop = currentPosition.top + 50;
            newLeft = currentPosition.left + 50;  

         break;

   }
   newTop = newTop + "px";
   newLeft = newLeft + "px";

   $div.animate({"left": newLeft, "top":newTop},1000);   
}
```

Comment: If you want complete random, use a random gen for the increment numbers. Also, check if you position after increment is greater then parent width, if so, starts to decrease it. That will make it not go beyond view or off screen. I use this method for gaming in javascript. SO if it hits border, it start going opposite way. Just some ideas for you.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<html>
  <head>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <h3>Click</h3>
    Small Leap:  <input type="radio" name="leap" value="small" id="smallRadio"><br>
    Medium Leap: <input type="radio" name="leap" value="medium" id="mediumRadio"><br>
    Big Leap:    <input type="radio" name="leap" value="large" id="largeRadio"><br>

    <button onclick="delegateJump()">Click!</button>

    <div class='a' data-top="0" data-left="0"></div>
    <div id='div1'></div>
    <div id='para'></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

CSS

```
div.a {
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
    margin:0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left:50%;

}
```

Javascript

```
 function showStyle() {
   //alert(" ss " );
   var id = document.querySelector('.a');
   var str = "";

   str = str + "position: " + id.style.position + ";";
   str += "<br>top: " + id.style.top;
   str += "<br>left: " + id.style.left;
   str += "<br>width: " + id.style.width;
   str += "<br>height: " + id.style.height;
   str += "<br>move top: " + id.dataset.top;
   str += "<br>move left: " + id.dataset.left;
   document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = str;
 }


  function smallJump(){
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * 25) - 10;
  }

  function mediumJump(){
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) - 50; 
  }


  function largeJump(){
     return Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) - 100;
  }

  function delegateJump() {
    var type = $('input[name="leap"]:checked').val();
    var div = $('.a')
    switch (type) {
      case "small":
        div.attr("data-top",  smallJump());
        div.attr("data-left", smallJump());
        break;
      case "medium":
        div.attr("data-top",  mediumJump());
        div.attr("data-left", mediumJump());
        break;
      case "large":
        div.attr("data-top",  largeJump());
        div.attr("data-left", largeJump());
        break;
      default: 
        div.attr("data-top",  0);
        div.attr("data-left", 0);
        break;
      }
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){
    animateDiv();

  });

  function makeNewPosition(x,y){

    var w = $(window).width()  - 50;
    var h = $(window).height() - 50;
    var x = parseInt(x, 10) || 0;
    var y = parseInt(y, 10) || 0;

    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w) + x;
    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h) + y;

    return [nh,nw];    

  }


  function animateDiv(){
    var newq = makeNewPosition.apply(null, [$('.a').attr('data-top'), $('.a').attr('data-left') ] );
    showStyle();

    $('.a').animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, function(){
         animateDiv();       
    });

  };
```

I changed a few things in your code.

1. I switched to using data attributes to hold the jump value.
2. With data attributes holding the value, the random jump animation uses that value to recalculate further jumps.
3. I added absolute positioning to the style for the div.
4. Your radio inputs needed a name, this allows you to grab a value from any of them with one selector.